# Does mongoDB has a mechanism like mysql ,which simple import .sql file into database?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, import

As the title goes , I wonder if MongoDB has a data file format to import directly ?I know that mysql has "sql" file format for it to import  directly .I am now in a project has the same requirement.Any one can tell me ?

Comment: Have you tried google searching yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB can import data using the mongoimport tool from JSON, CSV and TSV data format as you can see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

MongoDB internally represents data as a binary-encoded JSON ([BSON](http://bsonspec.org/)), so importing and exporting in JSON format is really fast and intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Of course.Mongodb use **mongodump/mongoexport** to export the data to outside files and use **mongorestore/mongoimport** to import data to its databases.more details , just reference to mongodb doc.mongodump and mongoexport ,mongorestore and mongoimport ,do have some differences .More details ,please refer to mongodb doc.